# Getting Internal Server Error while trying to access my site

Tags: apache, web, internal-server-error

I am getting this error.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@crimsonbux.com and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache/2.2.20 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.20 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
>   mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.6 Server at www.crimsonbux.com Port 80

Can someone please let me know how I can solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Answer (score 14):

you can check out the error log and get more information on what is causing the error. If you have an administrator gui provided to you by your host, that will be a good place to check. Here is an example video for cPanel (you will want to check with your host for how to access this report on your specific admin. interface):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzO1UNHZjZo

Comment: Thanks, you answer helped me to narrow down the issue. setting file permission to 644 worked.

Comment: Yes! In the error log, the error said: "myfile.php is writeable by group". The file had "664" permissions (which means "6" or read&write for the group). I've set permissions to 644, and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

I am also getting 500 Internal server error.
 [My Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693792/php-and-javascript-working-on-localhost-but-not-on-hosted-website)

Try checking the server error. In my case I used

```
cd /var/log
```

Then I used `sudo cat apache2/access.log`
(I was not able to `cd` into the apache2 directory directly, so this workaround)

also try `sudo cat apache2/error.log` if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If any of the above or other solution is not working for you then have a look at this link

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/public_html-is-writable-by-group-error.627391/

Here Cpanel community team member suggest that **public_html should have the permission set as 750**

This solution worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to a Japanese space (Zenkaku space) in my `PHP` file.

For `PHP`, it shows errors to the client side or logs errors to a file depends on how you configure the `php.ini` file. Either way, I got nothing from `PHP` when there is a Japanese space in the `myfile.php`

Answer (score 0):

My production web_server had the xdebugger setting disabled in it's php settings.
I reenabled the xdebugger and the server 500 error was replaced by the php script error in php page.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).