# Getting 500 - Internal server error when page taking more time to execute

Tags: php, yii

I have one website in Yii framework.

It was working fine till few days but since few days sometimes I am getting

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

This error occurs when there is more data load in page.

If I am on simple page where there is no need to get more data in page then it is working fine but when I am uploading or downloading or need more time to get data then mostly I am getting this error.

I have Windows server.

Can anybody guide me how can i solve this error?

Comment: Please include some code, we have no way of helping you like this

Comment: Please check these tywo links:- https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1903/Why+am+I+getting+a+500+Internal+Server+Error+message%3F.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693391/500-internal-server-error-for-php-file-not-for-html.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the webserver and php error logs, most probably is configuration problem

- memory_limit
- max_execution_time
- upload_max_filesize

check http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php