# 500 server error with network initiators of other and https redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, internal-server-error

I have a WordPress site that displays the following error in the browser console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

The site loads and functions fully. The error is not present on local development of the site and does not show up when the site is moved from production to staging. The .htaccess file is the same on all sites and shows no errors. The site is part of a large network of multisite domains and none of the subdomain sites have the error. It is only the primary domain that is affected. Plugins are network activated on all sites and do not appear to have any issues.

I have viewed the network tab and it appears that the error only shows up on three pages on the site. On an error page that loads normally, I see `other` under the initiator section. When I attempt to load the page through https, the initiator section displays `https redirect`.

[image]

Comment: Possibly you can find a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693391/500-internal-server-error-for-php-file-not-for-html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a new page, manually add the content in, and delete the old pages that displayed 500 internal server errors. I assume that something was corrupted in the WordPress database for these pages or they had incorrect permission previously set. Either way it is fixed now!