# Laravel 5 - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

My web server link structure is:
http://my_ip_address/~laravel/laravel/public/

When I go here: http://my_ip_address/~laravel/laravel, I see all folders & files, but when I am trying to access public folder I got 500 error

This is my public folder .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

I think, I have a problem with "~" symbol in URL.

How can I fix it up?

Thanks

p.s public + storage = chmod 777

Comment: Check the error log(s) to see why you get the 500 internal server error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [500 Internal Server Error for php file not for html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693391/500-internal-server-error-for-php-file-not-for-html)

Comment: Not answering the question - but I really would recommend that you point apache's document root to your public folder. e.g. `DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public` or similar. Also, why do you have a tilde in the directory name?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved my problem =)

the main folder (root) where laravel was install must have 755 chmod

in my case:
http://my_ip_address/~laravel/**laravel**/

laravel folder.