# SimpleXMLElement triggers "is currently unable to handle this request"

Tags: php, xml

We've recently upgraded to PHP 7, and I'm trying to get things working. We were using a rather random xml2array program which is no longer working, and I'd like to replace it with SimpleXMLElement rather than debug it.

- PHP is generally working.
- Errors are displaying.
- Everything works as long as I don't run SimpleXMLElement or simplexml_load_file.  As soon as I try and run these (using XML from PHP manual example), I get 500 error.

Comment: Can you enable the php error log? You'll see more errors in the logfile than in the output of your script.

Answer (score 0):

The key here was to find the error logs. This post has some useful notes on that: 
[500 Internal Server Error for php file not for html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693391/500-internal-server-error-for-php-file-not-for-html)

...Once I found the error logs, they informed me that SimpleXMLElement had not been installed, and this caused PHP to crash rather than display an error message. So to find the error, I had to track down the error file.

This post explains that PHP will refuse to catch a fatal error: [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)