# send session variables to email after submission of form

Tags: php, forms, session-variables

My form has 5 steps, every steps works fine and session variable pass to each pages. after submission, i want data to emailed back to admin. i have tried to write this, but it returns 500 error or white screen. please correct this where i am wrong here. here below is the codes for email processing after submission.

```
<?php
session_start();

$email_from = 'no-reply@indianvisaservice.org';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $_SESSION['givenname']."\r\n";.
    "Here is the message:\n $message"

$message = Application Reference No - $_SESSION['appid'] ."\r\n";
$message .= type of VISA Application - $_SESSION['visatype']."\r\n";
$message .= Port of Arrival - $_SESSION['arrivalport']."\r\n";
$message .= Application type - $_SESSION['appltype']."\r\n";
$message .= Applicant Name - $_SESSION['givenname']."\r\n";
$message .= Applicant Sex - $_SESSION['applsex']."\r\n";
$message .= Applicant Marital Status - $_SESSION['martstat']."\r\n";
$message .= Applicant Birthdate - $_SESSION['birthdate']."\r\n";
$message .= Applicant Passport No - $_SESSION['passportno']."\r\n";
$message .= Country of Birth - $_SESSION['countrybrth'] ."\r\n";
$message .= Religion of Applicant - $_SESSION['religionxx']."\r\n";
$message .= Educational Qualification - $_SESSION['edu_id']."\r\n";
$message .= Application Nationality by - $_SESSION['nationality_by']."\r\n";
$message .= Passport Issue Place - $_SESSION['issueplace'] ."\r\n";
$message .= Passport Issue date - $_SESSION['issuedate']."\r\n";
$message .= Visual Identification - $_SESSION['visual_d_mark']."\r\n";
$message .= is there Other Passport have - $_SESSION['tab']."\r\n";
$message. = Other Passport No - $_SESSION['oth_ppt_no'] ."\r\n";
$message .= Other Passport Issue Place - $_SESSION['oth_ppt_issue_place']."\r\n";
$message .= Other Passport Issue Date - $_SESSION['previssuedate']."\r\n";
$message .= Other Passport Nationality - $_SESSION['oth_ppt_nationality']."\r\n";
$message .= Other Passport Country Issue - $_SESSION['country_issue'] ."\r\n";
$message .= Father Name - $_SESSION['fthrname']."\r\n";
$message .= Father Nationality - $_SESSION['fathr_nation_id'] ."\r\n";
$message .= Father Previous Nationality - $_SESSION['fthrprevntl']."\r\n";
$message .= Father Place of Birth - $_SESSION['fthrpob']."\r\n";
$message .= Father City of Birth - $_SESSION['fthrcob']."\r\n";
$message .= Mother Name - $_SESSION['mthrname'] ."\r\n";
$message .= Mother Nationality - $_SESSION['mthr_nation_id']."\r\n";
$message .= Mother Previous Nationality - $_SESSION['mthrprevntl']."\r\n";
$message .= Mother Place of Birth - $_SESSION['mthrpob']."\r\n";
$message .= Mother City of Birth - $_SESSION['mthrcob']."\r\n";
$message .= Duration of Visit - $_SESSION['visitduration']."\r\n";
$message .= No of Visa Entry - $_SESSION['visa_entry_id']."\r\n";
$message .= Port of Exit from Country - $_SESSION['exitpointxx']."\r\n";
$message .= Places Likely to be Visit - $_SESSION['placelikelyvisited']."\r\n";
$message .= Places Likely to be Visit2 - $_SESSION['Placelikelyvisited2']."\r\n";
$message .= Do you have Old Visa - $_SESSION['oldvisa']."\r\n";
$message .= Old Visa Number - $_SESSION['old_visa_no']."\r\n";
$message .= Old Visa Type - $_SESSION['old_visa_type_id']."\r\n";
$message .= Old Visa Issue Place - $_SESSION['oldvisaissueplace']."\r\n";
$message .= Permanent Stay  - $_SESSION['permStay']."\r\n";
$message. = Refuse Details - $_SESSION['refuse_details']."\r\n";
$message .= Country Visited - $_SESSION['country_visited']."\r\n";
$message .= Name of Referance - $_SESSION['nameofsponsor_ind']."\r\n";
$message .= Referance Address - $_SESSION['referanceaddress']."\r\n";
$message .= Referance City - $_SESSION['referancecity']."\r\n";


$to = "mailme@imgrv.in";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers,$message);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<?php
session_start();

$email_from = 'no-reply@indianvisaservice.org';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Form submission";

$message = "Application Reference No - ".$_SESSION['appid']." \r\n";
$message .= "type of VISA Application - ".$_SESSION['visatype']."\r\n";
$message .= "Port of Arrival - ".$_SESSION['arrivalport']."\r\n";
// Concatenate all message like this
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user". $_SESSION['givenname']."\r\nHere is the message:\n $message";


$to = "mailme@imgrv.in";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');

?>
```

Comment: mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/www/indianvisaservice.org/form-processor.php on line 7

Comment: this is the error i m getting in error log after addition of your suggestion.

Comment: @GauravSingh add semicolon `;` after `$email_body` statement.

Comment: @bhaskar - added that, but error log still printing same error, as i mentioned above.

Comment: @GauravSingh, try this:  
`$message = "Application Reference No - ".$_SESSION['appid']." \r\n";`  and same rest of the lines.

Comment: @artier - now 500 errors have gone,, but facing another issue that is mails not delivering. i am not getting mails in mailbox.

Comment: From where you try to send mail, localhost or live server?

Comment: @artier - i am trying to send it from live server.

Comment: Change `mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers,$message);` to 
`mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);`

Answer (score 3):

**use proper way concatenation** for PHP code 
like:

```
$test ="abc";
echo $email_body = "You have received a new message from the user".$test."\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in beginning of this file. You can see syntax error. you have wrongly added `" "` for concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points:

1. Write this line below `$message` variable, `$message` is not defined yet.

   `$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user ".$_SESSION['givenname']."\r\n" . 
   "Here is the message:\n $message"; //not sure you made typo here but it should be like this. remove semicolon before dot because you are doing string concatenation.`
2. In mail function, I'm not sure why are you passing `$message` variable, last argument is for additional parameter [Click here for more info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

So it should be:

`mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);`

Hope this help you.

Comment: no luck ! its not working, still i am getting 500 error.

Comment: seems permission issue.. please have a look on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693391/500-internal-server-error-for-php-file-not-for-html

Comment: not getting it, tried to remove all $message variables from page to test , but, still getting the same error.