# HTTP ERROR 500 when trying to access php file on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, file-permissions, lamp, internal-server-error

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server with a LAMP stack. When I first set it up I copied what is inside of my project folder into /var/www/html/ folder. And it worked fine! Except that it gave me "Internal Server Error" when I tried to generate PDF file.

Next, I wanted to delete all of my files and reload them. I deleted html folder and everything inside, then I cloned my project from github repository, and then I renamed that folder's name to "html" again.

Unfortunately, now I cannot even login. The HTML login page shows, but login script doesn't work; again "Internal Server Error".

I guessed and read that it could be about folder/file permissions. I changed permissions of everything inside /var/www/ but no good! I have read those below:

https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-dedicated-web-server-for-free--net-2043

[500 Internal Server Error for php file not for html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693391/500-internal-server-error-for-php-file-not-for-html?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[500 Internal Server Error for php file not for html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693391/500-internal-server-error-for-php-file-not-for-html)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/450603/correct-permissions-for-sudo-lamp-var-www-directory

My final attempt was to apply the solution in the last link which is to run these commands on my server:

```
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

I really expected that this would work but it didn't help either. Please help, what should I do? What might be causing this problem?

(By the way, the server is on a private network, if it is somehow related)

Comment: got anything from logs?

Comment: Have you read the logs? Without the logs we are just reading tea leaves here.

Comment: I haven't considered that actually, I'm not so experienced in server management but I'll try to reach them now and share when I find.