# Codeignitor 3 Internal Server Error When Uploading onto subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-3, cpanel

It works fine on localhost.

when I upload onto subdomain on my cpanel.

It has this error [image]

My .htaccess file

```
    # <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#     SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
#     RewriteEngine On
#     RewriteBase /
# </IfModule> 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What debugging have you tried?  Did you check the logs?  Try removing your htaccess?  Try a plain `phpinfo();` page to see if PHP works at all? Maybe a plain HTML file to see if that works?  There are many questions here about what to do when you see a 500 error, did you try any of those suggestions?  Random eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693391/500-internal-server-error-for-php-file-not-for-html

Comment: Did you change the `$config['base_url']` in **application/config/config.php**?