# Error converting docx to pdf using Unoconv

Tags: php, libreoffice, unoconv

I am trying to convert .docx files to .pdf files using Unoconv. Libreoffice is installed on my server and the script works for another website on the server.

Using the line `use Unoconv\Unoconv;` results in an `HTTP ERROR 500`.

Does someone know why I get a `HTTP ERROR 500`?

Here is my script:

```
<?php
    require './Unoconv.php';
    use Unoconv\Unoconv;
        
    $originFilePath = './uf/invoice/17/word/202100021.docx';
    $outputDirPath  = './uf/invoice/17/pdf/202100021.pdf';
    
    Unoconv::convertToPdf($originFilePath, $outputDirPath);

    header("Content-type:application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=202100021.pdf");
?>
```

Here is my Unoconv.php script:

```
<?php

namespace Unoconv;

class Unoconv {

    public static function convert($originFilePath, $outputDirPath, $toFormat)
    {
        $command = 'unoconv --format %s --output %s %s';
        $command = sprintf($command, $toFormat, $outputDirPath, $originFilePath);
        system($command, $output);

        return $output;
    }

    public static function convertToPdf($originFilePath, $outputDirPath)
    {
        return self::convert($originFilePath, $outputDirPath, 'pdf');
    }

    public static function convertToTxt($originFilePath, $outputDirPath)
    {
        return self::convert($originFilePath, $outputDirPath, 'txt');
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Is it really a backslash or should it be a forward slash?

Comment: I think ik should be a backslash. But I already tried it with a forward slash :)

Comment: where `$result1` is declared and set? we don't see the all code involved here

Comment: are both files (your script and Unoconv.php) are in the same folder?

Comment: @Alex yes. The script and Unoconv.php are in the same folder. $result1 if working fine, You can read it like: "$map1 ='map1'; $filename = 'test';"

Comment: *"Does someone know why I get a HTTP ERROR 500?"* https://stackoverflow.com/a/17693462/12763954

Comment: Also you don't send the PDF to the browser.

Comment: @Olivier I still get a HTTP ERROR 500, with or without `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.

Comment: Which library are you using? Can you please share the URL to a Git repo?

Comment: @John easiest way to trace the `500 Internal Server Error` is by enabling `error_reporting` in your php script. i.e. `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); ini_set('error_reporting', 32767);`

Comment: @John What are your output folder permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Start from wrapping your code with `try...catch` to get the error message first:

```
<?php
try {
    require 'Unoconv.php';
    use Unoconv\Unoconv;
    
    $map1 = $_SESSION['companyid'];
    $filename = $result1['filename'];
    
    $originFilePath = './uf/doc/'.$map1.'/word/'.$filename.'.docx';
    $outputDirPath  = './uf/doc/'.$map1.'/pdf/'.$filename.'.pdf';
    
    Unoconv::convertToPdf($originFilePath, $outputDirPath);
    
    header("Content-type:application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=".$filename.".pdf");
    readfile($outputDirPath);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: @John that is kind impossible. Try `die('test')` at the very 1st line in your script. It looks like the problem is outside of your script if we can't `catch` it.

Comment: `die('test')` did not change anything. I still get a Error 500. The script in my first post is exactly what I am using. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @John that is impossible. delete all content and keep only `die('test');` it seem you  never get to this script at all.

Comment: But it is happening :). With only `die('test');` I get the text `test` in my browser :)

Comment: @John as per Noelpotnic comment I've adjusted my code. Try it again to detect the real error message that breaks your page.

Comment: I still get a Error 500. When I run the script with try & catch. But I have a little update. When I run the script without try & catch my browser generates an empty pdf file. It downloads the file 202100021.pdf without any content. I also can see that the folder is empty, there are no files converted.

Comment: @John it is either 500 errror or file is pushed. If you say that file is pushed to browser - I doubt that you have 500 error. It seem you've missed the part that push the real content `readfile(...)`

Comment: I see a error 500 page in Chrome. In Firefox I see a blank page. But in the console I can see that there is a Error 500.

There is something with the `use Unoconv\Unoconv;` line. With this line I see a Error 500 and it does not generate a PDF file

Comment: `try... catch` should output some error message

Comment: @John join zoom meeting and share your screen I can try to help if you are online now https://us02web.zoom.us/j/89783185489?pwd=SnRXZFpUUk5tcHhESVFHUldCbHNYdz09

Answer (score 2):

@Alex is correct about wrapping in try/catch first, but should the syntax be:

```php
...
} catch(\Exception $e){
...
```

Comment: Nice catch. Thank you.

Comment: Pun intended ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I've observed that LibreOffice can be a little quirky when doing conversions, especially when running in headless mode from a webserver account.

The simplest thing to try is to modify `unoconv` to use the same Python binary that is shipped with LibreOffice:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

should be (after checking where libreoffice is installed)

```
#!/opt/libreoffice7.1/program/python
```

Otherwise, I have worked around the problem by invoking libreoffice directly (**without Unoconv**):

```
    $dir    = dirname($docfile);
    // Libreoffice saves here
    $pdf    = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($docfile, '.docx').'.pdf';
    $ret = shell_exec("export HOME={$dir} && /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir '{$dir}' '{$docfile}' 2>&1");
    if (file_exists($pdf)) {
        rename($pdf, $realPDFName);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Note the `export HOME={$dir}` directive, to ensure that temporary lock files will be saved in the current directory where, presumably, the web server has full permissions. If this requirement isn't met,
**LibreOffice will silently fail** (or at least, it *will* fail - that much I observed - and I haven't been able to locate an error message anywhere - I found out what was  going on through the use of `strace`).

So your code would become:

```
$originFilePath = './uf/invoice/17/word/202100021.docx';
$outputDirPath  = './uf/invoice/17/pdf/202100021.pdf';

$dir    = dirname($originFilePath);
$pdf    = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($originFilePath, '.docx').'.pdf';
$ret = shell_exec("export HOME={$dir} && /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir '{$dir}' '{$originFilePath}' 2>&1");
// $ret will contain any errors
if (!file_exists($pdf)) {
    die("Conversion error: " . htmlentities($ret));
}
rename($pdf, $outputDirPath);

header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=202100021.pdf");
readfile($outputDirPath);
```

I assume that libreoffice is present in the usual alternatives link of "/usr/bin/libreoffice", otherwise you need to retrieve its path with the terminal command of "which libreoffice". Or, from a php script,

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
print "If this works:\n";
system('which libreoffice 2>&1');
print "\n-- otherwise a different attempt, returning too much information --\n";
system('locate libreoffice');
```