# 500 Internal Server Error for php file (not for html) after installing SSL

Tags: php, linux, ssl, debian, fastcgi

After installing SSL on the server, the .php files stopped working and gave an error 500:
https://freshfinance.pl/empty.php

HTML works fine:
https://freshfinance.pl/

I have 2 entries in error.log:

> [Sun Nov 07 13:01:47.229672 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 4630]
> (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 162.158.102.105:56384]
> mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server [Sun Nov 07
> 13:01:47.229742 2021] [core:error] [pid 4630] [client
> 162.158.102.105:56384] End of script output before headers: empty.php

I have read other forum posts about a similar issue but none have been helpful (e.g. [500 Internal Server Error for php file not for html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693391/500-internal-server-error-for-php-file-not-for-html))

What could be causing the problem on my server?

Comment: This has nothing to do with SSL since one gets the same error with pure HTTP link. Something is wrong with your PHP file but, but since there is nothing known about it one cannot help what exactly is wrong with it.

Comment: Before installing SSL, the .php files opened without any problem. After installing SSL (with Cloudflare + change DNS), .php (even empty) does not work for both http:// and https://

Comment: In this case you likely messed up something when installing SSL. Since it is unknown what exactly you did one cannot help here. The error message though says clearly that something is wrong with the PHP file itself, so maybe there were some expectations in the code which are no longer true after you made the changes for SSL. It might also be completely unrelated to SSL, i.e. just happen to break at the same time for a different reason.