# Php and javascript working on localhost but not on hosted website

Tags: javascript, php, json, drupal

I implemented a search form that has 3 drop down `<select>` tags
The first 2 drop downs have static options while I used a javascript to create the options of the third drop down. The javascript is based on `onchange` event of 2nd drop down and is stored in `searchideas.js` file

This `searchideas.js` file calls `datasupplier.php` using `GET` method through `XMLHttpRequest`. All works fine on my localhost but when I hosted it on the live website, the options for the third drop down does not gets generated. `xmlhttp.readyState` becomes `4` but `xmlhttp.status` becomes `500` which corresponds to Internal server error.

I have also moved the `searchideas.js` and `datasupplier.php` in the same folder where my webpage containing the dropdowns is located but to no avail.

How can I over come this error?

My `searchideas.js` is:

```
function searchideas( )
{
    var state = document.getElementById("stateID").value; 
    var county = document.getElementById("countyID").value; 
    var town = document.getElementById("townID").value;
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {        
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            var selectList = document.getElementById('townID');
            var val = xmlhttp.responseText; 
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(val); 
            for (var i in jsonData) 
            {
              var option = document.createElement('option');
              option.value = "http://www.mywebsite.com" + i;
              option.text = jsonData[i];
              selectList.appendChild(option);
            }
        }   
    } 
    var url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/sites/all/themes/danland/datasupplier.php?stateID=" + state + "&countyID=" + county + "&townID=" + town;    
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

My `datasupplier.php` is:

```
<?php 

$stateID = $_GET['stateID'];
$countyID = $_GET['countyID'];
$townID = $_GET['townID'];

$states = array();
$states['SC'] = "Stories";
$states['TL'] = "Novels";
$counties = array();
$counties['SC']['PRACT'] = 'By Interest';
$counties['SC']['SERV'] = 'By Choice';
$counties['TL']['PRACT'] = 'By Interest';
$counties['TL']['SERV'] = 'By Choice';

$towns = array();
$towns['SC']['PRACT']['/index.php?q=sc%3Fpract%3Ffai'] = "Fairy Tale";
$towns['SC']['PRACT']['/index.php?q=sc%3Fpract%3Fedu'] = "Education";
$towns['SC']['SERV']['/index.php?q=sc%3Fserv%3Ffic'] = "Fiction";

$towns['TL']['PRACT']['/index.php?q=tl%3Fpract%3Fzom'] = "Zombie";
$towns['TL']['PRACT']['/index.php?q=tl%3Fpract%3Fedu'] = "Education";
$towns['TL']['SERV']['/index.php?q=tl%3Fserv%3Fsal'] = "Sales";
$towns['TL']['SERV']['/index.php?q=tl%3Fserv%3Fstr'] = "Strategy";



if($stateID && !$countyID && !$townID)
{
    echo json_encode( $counties[$stateID] );
} 
elseif( $stateID && $countyID && !$townID ) 
{
    echo json_encode( $towns[$stateID][$countyID] );
}
elseif( isset($villages[$stateID][$countyID][$townID]) ) 
{
    echo json_encode( $villages[$stateID][$countyID][$townID] );
} 
else 
{
    echo '{}';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you because of file permission , changing permission from `755` to `644` worked.  If yours is related to permissions, try setting `datasupplier.php`'s permission to `644`.