# My php pages in my hosting account display server error 500 when accessed

Tags: php

I recently uploaded a website for a friend in byethost just for viewing purposes. When I tried to check if it is working, all HTML pages are working correctly but when I access php pages a server error 500 occurs. What can be the problem?

I have checked for a `.htaccess` files as many forums here suggests but to no avail since my account does not have that page. It only occurs when I alter php configuration in the cpanel which suggests to put magic quotes `'on'` or `'off'` but after, the php page displays no server error but it displays a blank.

I had edited the connection php page to `"@ mysql...."` Instead of `"mysqli"` can this be the reason? And can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Post your database connection code...done

Comment: error 500 can have many reasons, most of them are  server-side, if you have access to error log on your server. Try upload blank(empty) `php` file and if even this throw error 500, you should contact websupport. If simple php file is working, problem is in your script

Comment: <?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_conblog = "sql101.byethost32.com";
$database_conblog = "vidacom_sys_db";
$username_conblog = "root_b32_16644380";
$password_conblog = "b32_16644380";
$conblog = @ mysql_pconnect($hostname_conblog, $username_conblog, $password_conblog) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>

Comment: What changes should I do to the script since I had uploaded recently to that account a joomla working website and it had no problem but I removed it since my friend wasn't impressed with it and I had to use Dreamweaver to create the website.

Answer (score 0):

You need some debugging.
In your php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

In .htaccess file:

```
php_flag display_errors 1
```

Also, you might want to check this out: [Getting Internal Server Error while trying to access my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179706/getting-internal-server-error-while-trying-to-access-my-site)

Comment: Thanks for posting that link, it has helped me learn something new but I haven't found a solution, I have downloaded winScp and modified the permissions to 0711,0755.0644,0744 and 7777 but it still displays a blank page when I reload, I have also set. The ddebug code inone of my  php pages and i .htaccess The other but still nothing.